# Adding Json data in a variable in ROBOT framework

Tags: testing, robotframework

I am starting to work on automating API requests using ROBOT framework and came across the below issue.

I have this JSON data

```
{
"password": "123456789",
"username": "test@test.com"
}
```

I want to put the above in a variable and generate a token as a response.

Previously I had used the below

```
${body}=  create dictionary       username=test@test.com     password=123456789
```

I got the below error response
HTTPError: 415 Client Error: Unsupported Media Type for url:

Can someone help me on this please.

**Updated Code**

```
*** Settings *** 
Library String 
Library Collections 
Library RequestsLibrary 

*** Variables *** 
Credentials 
${prod_url} localhost:3000/api 

*** Test Cases *** 
User login and token generation.

Create Session demo ${prod_url} 

${body}= create dictionary username=test@test.com password=123456789 

${header}= create dictionary Content-Type=application/json 

${login}= post on session demo /login data=${body} headers=${header} 

log to console ${login.content}
```

Above is full code. What I need is the username and password needs to be in JSON format because My API is accepting only those values..

Comment: The response is because of the request's format, most likely the content-type header, whose value is most likely needed to be set to "application/json". Add the code where you're making the request; and make sure what are the supported types by the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `data` argument, try passing the dictionary to the `json` one:

```
${login}=  post on session    demo    /login    json=${body}  
  headers=${header}
```

When you use the `data`, the library passes as-is the string representation of the object - and in python a str of a dict is `{'password': '123456789' ,...`  - e.g. it uses single quotes, not double ones, which is an invalid json.
Passing the dict to the other argument, `json`, will make it convert to the proper format.

Comment: Solves part of the problem !! thank you ... I would comment again in case I am stuck